# Why I get a "Access is denied" error by Spring Security and Keycloak?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I setup a Keycloak server with Docker. Configured the realm and client and so on. I managed successfully to write a Spring Boot service for some RestControllers. Work so on.

But when I try to use Spring Security with Keycloak Adapter, I'm stuck.

Here is my SecurityConfig:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
class SecurityConfig : KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var keycloakClientRequestFactory: KeycloakClientRequestFactory

    @Bean
    fun keycloakConfigResolver(): KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver = KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver()

    @Bean
    override fun sessionAuthenticationStrategy(): SessionAuthenticationStrategy =
        NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy()

    @Autowired
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val keycloakAuthProvider: KeycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider()
        keycloakAuthProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(SimpleAuthorityMapper())
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthProvider)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        super.configure(http)
        http.cors().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy()).and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/apps/manual-data-collection/**").hasRole("user")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
    }

    /**
     * https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#avoid-double-bean-registration
     */
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager::class)
    override fun httpSessionManager(): HttpSessionManager = HttpSessionManager()

}
```

Now I try the access the server, but get a 403 Forbidden Error. Following is log by spring:

```
2020-01-08 14:08:01.817 DEBUG 12396 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/apps/manual-data-collection/document-templates'; against '/apps/manual-data-collection/**'
2020-01-08 14:08:01.817 DEBUG 12396 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /apps/manual-data-collection/document-templates; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_user')]
2020-01-08 14:08:01.817 DEBUG 12396 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@bc432bbc: Principal: willy; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@42db7613; Not granted any authorities
2020-01-08 14:08:01.818 DEBUG 12396 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3d0602a7, returned: -1
2020-01-08 14:08:01.818 DEBUG 12396 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

What confuse me is, that it says: `Not granted any authorities`. If I leave out the part, everything works fine. The necessary roles (in this case 'user') are stored in the realm. The JWT token also provides these. I have no idea why it wouldn't work.

Edit:
Which I should mention. The Spring Boot Server should only be used as a REST server for an Angular application and is therefore `STATELESS`.

Comment: Just a guess: `hasRole('ROLE_user')` might indicate that Spring security is looking for a role named `ROLE_user`. Did you name it that way in your realm?

Comment: In realm role is ```user```. Spring Security used Prefix ```ROLE_```, so I used the ```SimpleAuthorityMapper``` to map the keycloak roles to spring roles. Or did I misunderstand something? Nevertheless, I simply created a role with the name ```ROLE_user```. Unfortunately it did not work either.

Comment: Change `.antMatchers("/apps/manual-data-collection/**").hasRole("user")` to `.antMatchers("/apps/manual-data-collection/**").hasRole("ROLE_user")`

Comment: @BilalShah then I get an error: 
```IllegalArgumentException: role should not start with 'ROLE_' since it is automatically inserted. Got 'ROLE_user' ```

Comment: can you post your Database authentication class where you are making request to db to check if user exist or not.

Comment: @BilalShah since he's using Keycloak there is no (direct) database authentication. Also note that the user does exist (`Authenticated: true`) but the role doesn't seem to get matched.

Comment: I rather think that Spring Security can't find any roles. That would explain the error: ```Not granted any authorities```. But I don't know why.

Comment: your roles should be named `user` but your spring application should check for `hasRole("ROLE_user")` if you are doing method security

Comment: but if you are (as you are doing here) checking on a url endpoint, then you do `.hasRole('user')`

Comment: Can you share your project on github?

Comment: @BilalShah I try to create a minimal project in 7-8 hours and share it on github.

Comment: where is the link?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I found my mistake. I had activated the following in the application.yml:

```
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
```

But it must be `false`. [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_java_adapter_config) say's following:

> **use-resource-role-mappings** - 
>   If set to true, the adapter will look inside the token for application level role mappings for the user. If false, it will look at the realm level for user role mappings. This is OPTIONAL. The default value is false.

Comment: Perfect, absolutely works!